# Horror/Fantasy novel set in the UK town of Grimsby

Tags: story-identification, horror, parallel-universe

I am looking for a novel, which I believe ultimately ended in a trilogy that is set within the town of Grimsby in the UK.

I believe that the story was written in the last 7 years and was a horror/fantasy novel which started with an individual leaving a local pub and then walking through the town. The town was I believe slightly "twisted" in a similar but not as bad way as the upside down from Stranger Things and was a partial parallel universe from the "real" world.

I feel that this change had happened while the individual was in the pub or they did not immediately recognise that the change had happened either due to alcohol consumption or from the changes initially being very subtle.

I believe the author had a first name of Anthony/Tony/Ant and the book was the authors first published work and was print on demand published so was unlikely to have been widely available.

I don't have much more information that that I am afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [*The Night Out*: 1 (The trilogy) Paperback – 19 Feb. 2018 by Ants Ambridge](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B079X37Z3N/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i2)?

> After a spectacularly bad day at work, possibly resulting in the loss of his job, Jake decides to go out drinking with friends to commiserate himself. After that night, he is never seen again.
>
> *The Night Out* follows Jake’s misadventures on the evening, whilst focussing on his family and friends who mourn his loss or continue in a vain search for him. The darkly comic story blends a variety of genres and promises many twists and turns throughout.